# select those fields that has more than one entry

Tags: mysql, sql

i don't get it of how  to write a simple sql statement that shows only those entries
that appers more than once.

e.x.

```
NodeID  Number

0       12
1       12
2       12
0       13
1       13
0       14
1       15
2       16
1       17
```

Select `nodeID`, `number` from Table where number appearing more than once with different `nodeID`

Result:

```
NodeID  Number
0       12
1       12
2       12
0       13
1       13
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Number
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY Number
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b ON a.Number = b.Number
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bca06/2)

Another way is to use `EXISTS`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    TableName b
            WHERE   a.Number = b.Number
            GROUP   BY Number
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bca06/3)

Comment: This selects records even if `12` is appearing with repeating `nodeID` http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97d68/1/0 . Think I'm misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @Ejay the answer is based on the example above. You have a point about duplicates but it can be avoided if the OP has unique constraint for every combination.

Comment: @Ejay here's the solution for you example, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97d68/4

Comment: that's great :) Your solution indeed solved OP's problem. I was just was curious about duplicates case

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT NodeID , Number FROM TableName WHERE Number IN
(SELECT Number FROM TableName  GROUP BY Number HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `EXISTS` without `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT nodeid, 
       number 
FROM   Table1 t1 
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1 
              FROM   Table1 t2 
              WHERE  t1.number = t2.number 
                     AND t1.nodeid <> t2.nodeid)
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5edee/8/0)

Answer (score 0):

My first idea was to do a self join like  below, but it won't work because the grouping happens afterwards.

> SELECT T1.NodeId, T2.Number, COUNT(T2.Number) C
>      FROM Table T1
>      INNER JOIN Table T2 USING(Number)
>      WHERE C > 1
>      GROUP BY T2.Number

Hence you must do the grouping select first, then make the join:

```
SELECT NodeId, Number
FROM Table T1
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT Number, COUNT(Number) C
     FROM Table
    WHERE C > 1
    GROUP BY Number
) T2 USING(Number)
```